# session setting php.ini in runtime

Tags: php, session, ini

the function set_cookie_params allows to configure in runtime the directives that are responsible for the cookie session. in php.net it says that this function needs to be called in every request before session_start(). is it possible that we need to call it just before the session_start that creates a new session (in the respond we will create a cookie) and not in a script that we continue an existing session, and that's because these directives configures the creation of the cookie session, and if we don't create a cookie in the next script then it Is useless to configure it.
in addition, do we have to invoke ini_set() to configure a session directive, in every script or just in the script that starts a new session (like the directive session.gc_maxlifetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can setup an new session start function if your logic don't allow to setup your application before and call the options. but the correct way is to bootstrap your application and (maybee include) a config file that set all your options. like

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
//bootstrap file    
session_set_cookie_params(...);
session_start();
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('bootstrap.php');
//DoStuff
```

---

of curse you can override php functions but this not the way to achieve your task

```
rename_function('session_start', 'new_session_start');
override_function('session_start', '', 'return override_session_start();');

function override_session_start(){
   // set settings
   session_set_cookie_params(...);
   new_session_start();
}

session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

`session_start` either restores a session *or* starts a new session, if there is no session applicable to the currently set configuration. In other words, you don't know whether there already is a session or not when you call `session_start`, and session start will set the cookie based on the current ini settings and/or `session_set_cookie_params` settings. In addition, `session_name` influences both what name will be used in the set cookie *and* what name will be looked for in cookies when calling `session_start`.

As such, you always need to configure everything every time before you call `session_start`.